# Trouble Setting Up Ad-hoc Network From Terminal

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, adhoc

I'm trying to connect to a server I'm running in C on a computer on a wireless ad-hoc network. The problem is when I'm to connect from another computer on the network using telnet it doesn't work. I can ping the IP address (192.168.0.1) but using:

```
 telnet 192.168.0.1 8889
```

results in the error  "Connection Refused" (The server is listening on port 8889 which I've verified).

I've investigated further and found that setting up my ad-hoc network using network manager solves this problem. Currently I'm setting up my ad-hoc network via terminal and I would like to keep it this way. The ad-hoc network is being setup with the following commands:

```
 sudo service network-manager stop
 sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc essid 'rgd' channel AUTO key OFF
```

Where wlan0 is my wireless device. 
I'm not sure why this error is occurring. Can anybody help me with this?

Edit: @Huygens netstat -tlpen displays the following

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address  Foreign Address  State    User  Inode   PID/Program name

tcp     0      0     0.0.0.0:48727      0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN   1000  302920      13098/socket    
tcp     0      0     127.0.0.1:631      0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN      0  273220      933/cupsd     
tcp     0      0     0.0.0.0:54880      0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN   1000  304089      13148/socket    
tcp     0      0     127.0.1.1:53       0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN      0  12886       1606/dnsmasq    
tcp6    0      0        ::1:631           :::*       LISTEN      0  273219      933/cupsd       
tcp6    0      0        ::1:54822         :::*       LISTEN   1000  46736       3297/java
```

I don't see my server here for some reason :(

I've added the server code I'm running here for further reference:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>  //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>   //inet_addr
#include<unistd.h>  //write

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
int socket_desc , new_socket , c;
struct sockaddr_in server , client;
char *message;

//Create socket
socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
if (socket_desc == -1) 
{
printf("Could not create socket");
}

//Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_port = htons( 8889 );

//Bind
if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
puts("bind failed");
return 1;
}
puts("bind done");

//Listen
listen(socket_desc , 3);

//Accept and incoming connection
puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
if (new_socket<0)
{
  perror("accept failed");
  return 1;
}

puts("Connection accepted");

//Reply to the client
message = "Hello Client , I have received your connection. But I have to go now, bye\n";
write(new_socket , message , strlen(message));

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You will probably have higher chance of getting an answer by posting at superuser.com.

Comment: After you configure wlan0, what does simply typing iwconfig report? What IP address was assigned? Could you check that your server is bound to the wlan0 interface once it is configured? You can use `sudo netstat -tlpen` for that and put the output in your question.

Comment: Maybe you have to set the IP address after the interface is up & running.

Comment: @Huygens sudo netstat -tlpen provides this:

Comment: @Rodrigo How would I set up the IP address from terminal?

Comment: @user1721182: To set the IP and mask: `ip addr add 192.168.0.2/24 dev wlan0` or if you are still using the old ifconfig: `ifconfig wlan0 add 192.168.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0`. Note that you may need to set the interface _up_ if it is not yet there: `ip link set dev wlan0 up` or `ifconfig wlan0 up`. Use then command `ip addr show wlan0` or `ifconfig wlan0` to see the status of the interface.

Comment: Seeing netstat, your server is not listening on any TCP socket. Is it a UDP server? If so, try using `netstat -upen`.

Comment: That's strange. It is a TCP server. I can telnet to the socket itself from the same computer that the server is running on. 

I've tried setting up the IP on like rodrigo said and if i do that then I can see my server listed via netstat. However then for some reason I cannot detect the network on other computers

Answer (score 0):

You have to do things in the proper order I think.

First you should set-up your network interfaces. Once done, you should check that you can ping your network interfaces and that if you have a firewall that it would allow incoming connection on port 8889. To see of you have a firewall activated: `iptables -L` if there are any rule, then you have a firewall. In addition, make sure that each network interface has the expected IP address: `ifconfig`.

For testing purpose and if you are on a safe network, you can temporarily disable the firewall: `iptables -F` (precede it by sudo if you require super user privilege).

Then, you can start your server. Check that it is up and running (via `ps wux`) and check that it is in listening mode via `netstat -tlpen`.

Now try to telnet to it via `telnet 192.168.0.1 8889`.

PS: Of course your ad-hoc network should be on a different subnet than your local network. So if you are using both your ethernet (cable) network and an ad-hoc wifi network, each should be on a different subnet: e.g. 192.168.0.1/24 and 192.168.1.1/24.